# WAR Runs in Jetty on Red Hat but Not on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, maven, jetty, redhat, maven-jetty-plugin

I have a WAR file that runs fine using the jetty-maven-plugin, but it won't run using the same version (version 8) of stand-alone jetty.  It just returns a "SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE" error.  On a whim, knowing that the WAR originally ran on Jetty 6.1.26, I tried using it.  That seemed to clear up the logs, but I receive a blank page when I hit the url in my browser. Any ideas as to what the issue might be?

Oddly, the war runs successfully on an instance on Jetty 6.1.26 on a Red Hat server, but not on the same version of Jetty on Ubuntu...

---

UPDATE: This appears to have been a system-dependent issue.  I tried this on another Ubuntu installation and it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Which JVM are you using?  I know that the default in Ubuntu is the OpenJDK JRE, is Red Hat using the Sun JVM?

Comment: I just updated the description.  I don't have access to the machine that it was failing on at the moment - I'll check on Monday to see which JVM it is running.

Comment: Both boxes were using the Sun JVM - Not sure what caused the issue, but we're up and running now, which is what ultimately matters.  Thanks for your help!